# Asp.Net DropDownList tooltip ou title com JS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dropdown

Estou iniciando em Javascript, e gostaria que meu `DropDownList` de um controle `.ascx`, ao selecionar um item, exibisse o seu valor completo quando passar o mouse em cima, como se fosse um tooltip ou title. 
   Este é o meu DropDown:

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="dropdown" ID="ddlDescricao 
 OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDescricao_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        runat="server" TabIndex="0">
```

Tentei fazer dessa forma:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function addToolTip() {
        var ddl = document.getElementById('<%= ddlDescricao.ClientID %>');
        for (var i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) {
            ddl.options[i].title = ddl.options[i].text;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Porém não está dando certo.

Estou usando jQuery 1.7

Desde Já Obrigado a todos.

--Edit 11/02/2016 08:27

Estou invocando a função pelo onmouseover do dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta utilizar a seguinte instrução:

```
$("select[name*='ddlDescricao']")
    .prop('title', $("select[name*='ddlDescricao'] option:selected").text());
```

O seletor foi feito utilizando o atribute contains porque o nome dos controles normalmente é modificado na rendização.

Atualização: 
Adicionando o código da segunda objeção

```
var $dropdown = $("select[name*='ddlDescricao']");
$dropdown.prop('title', $dropdown.attr('title') + ': ' + $dropdown.children("option:selected").text());
```

Comment: Boa tarde, obrigado a principio deu certo, porém, quando há mais de um dropdown na pagina, ela vai dando um "append" nos valores do tittle, por exemplo o valor do dropdown1 é carlos, o valor do dropdown2 é vinte, no dropdown2 o "title" ficara como carlosvinte, ao invés de apenas "vinte".

Comment: Alterei a resposta

Comment: Bom dia Felipe, obrigado pela resposta, mas infelizmente acontece praticamente o mesmo, veja na imagem da edição que anexei.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi muito bem o problema, mas se precisa alterar o título de um elemento utilizando javascript pode fazer desta forma:

```html
<script>
   function alteraTitulo() {
      var ddl = document.getElementById('ddlTeste');
      var title = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
       ddl.title = title;
    }
 </script>

<select id="ddlTeste" onchange='alteraTitulo()'>
<option>Valor 1</option>
<option>Valor 2</option>
<option>Valor 3</option>
</select>
```

Dessa forma eu seleciono o elemento em questão em `var ddl = document.getElementById('ddlTeste');`, obtenho o texto da opção selecionado var `title = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;` e altero o título `ddl.title = title;`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nccf8ay2/)

### Edição

Uma solução simples (usando apenas javascript) para vários `selects` seria você passar o id do elemento para sua função. Seria mais ou menos isso:

```html
<script>
   function alteraTitulo(id) {
      var ddl = document.getElementById(id);
      var title = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
       ddl.title = title;
    }
 </script>

<select id="ddlTeste" onchange='alteraTitulo("ddlTeste")'>
<option>Valor 1</option>
<option>Valor 2</option>
<option>Valor 3</option>
</select>

<select id="ddlTeste1" onchange='alteraTitulo("ddlTeste1")'>
<option>Teste 1</option>
<option>Teste 2</option>
<option>Teste 3</option>
</select>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nccf8ay2/1/)

Utilizando o jQuery você pode realizar a troca ao executar o evento [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/), fazendo assim a substituição do título. Ficaria assim seu código:

```js
$('select').change(function(){
var ddl = $(this);
var title = ddl.find("option:selected").text();
ddl.prop('title', title); 
console.log(title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option>Valor 1</option>
<option>Valor 2</option>
<option>Valor 3</option>
</select>

<select>
<option>Teste 1</option>
<option>Teste 2</option>
<option>Teste 3</option>
</select>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nccf8ay2/3/)

Comment: Bom dia, obrigado pela resposta, mas dessa forma quando houver mais de um dropdown em tela, o valor selecionado em um dropdown, sera estabelecido para todos os demais.

Comment: Eu pensei em uma forma de fazer isso, porém não sei como implementar, esse é o codigo para ter uma noção mais ou menos do que eu tentei fazer:` function alteraTitulo() {
        var $dropdown = $("select[name*='ddlDescricao']");`

        for (i = 0; i < $dropdown.children.length; i++) {
            $dropdown[i].prop('title', $dropdown[i].find("option:selected").text());
        }
    }

Comment: @CarlosHenrique Você está usando somente javascript ou jquery? Mas é exatamente isso que você quer? Claro, funcionando para mais e um `dropdown`

Comment: Estou utilizando jQuery e javascript, qualquer um que me proponha a solução. O que eu quero é que quando eu passar o mouse por cima de um valor selecionado de um dropdown, ele me exiba o que esta escrito no valor selecionado, por que há casos em que o dropdown tem espaço para 20 caracteres e o valor possui 40 por exemplo, assim o usuario não saberia o que esta selecionando, porém, as soluções que tentei funcionam se houver apenas um dropdown em tela, quando há mais de 1 dropdown, ele se perde, acaba atribuindo o valor do dropdown anterior ou proximo, vou tentar implementar a sua ultima edição.